# Showing $Lv\leq 0$ for second order divergence form elliptic operator

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Evans page 346 - edition 1 - chapter 6  - problem 5

Let $u$ be a smooth solution of $$Lu=-\sum_{i,j=1}^n a^{ij}(x)u_{x_ix_j}=0$$ in $U$. Set $v=|Du|^2+\lambda u^2$. Show that $Lv\leq 0$ in $U$ for $\lambda$ sufficiently large.

I found $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} v = \sum_{k=1}^n 2u_{x_kx_i}u_{x_k}+2\lambda u u_{x_i}$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}v= \sum_{k=1}^n\left(2u_{x_kx_ix_j}u_{x_k}+ 2u_{x_kx_i}u_{x_ix_j}\right)+2u_{x_j}u_{x_i}+2uu_{x_ix_j}$$

So then when I take $Lv$ a few of these terms will vanish, since $Lu$ will appear twice. So I get:
$$Lv= -\sum_{i,j=1}^n \left(a^{ij}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n u_{x_k x_ix_j}u_{x_k}\right)+2\lambda u_{x_j}u_{x_i}\right)$$
Assuming I've done this right, how can I show that $Lv\leq 0$?

Comment: Have a look at page 5 http://homepage.ntu.edu.tw/~d04221001/Notes/Problems%20and%20Solutions%20Section/Evans%20PDE/Evans%20PDE%20Solution%20Chapter%206%20Second-Order%20Elliptic%20Equations.pdf